# how do I remove the owner from an s3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

so I'm in a highly constrained corporate environment - so things like changing accounts aren't possible for me - and I've ended up in a situation I don't know how to solve.

I have lambda, an S3 bucket, and a machine that can talk to the lan and talk to the s3 bucket.  They all run as different accounts (something I can't control).  I have terabytes of data I need to copy from the lan machine into s3, then access from the lambda.

If I write something to the bucket from the lambda, and read it back, it works perfectly - but of course if I copy something from the lan machine into the bucket - the lambda can't read it.  I do

```sh
aws s3api list-objects ...
```

- and I can see that they are owned by the machine account.    If I do a

```sh
aws s3api put-object-acl --acl bucket-owner-full-control ...
aws s3api get-object-acl ...
```

I can see another grant has appeared, but it still doesn't work from the lambda - because the lambda is running as a third account - ie not the one uploading, and not the owner of the bucket.

so - is there any way, either at the individual object level or at the cloud formation level to basically say either:

- set this object to be readable by anyone who has getobject on the bucket    or
- this account can read anything *in* the bucket, regardless of owner?

Essentially I just want permissions at the bucket level - I don't want any permissions INSIDE the bucket - so if you have access to read any object in the bucket, you should have access to read *every* object, regardless of how it got in there?

Comment: When you're uploading from your LAN machine to S3 in the first place, add `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` (also note dashes, not underscores) when you run `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` so you don't have to put the ACL independently later. This won't fix the 3rd Lambda permissions (that's not the point of this comment).

Comment: I mistyped the underscores when preparing this - have fixed... but the point is bucket-owner-full-control doesn't help me at all, because the lambda isn't running as the bucket owner

Comment: To allow the 3rd account to access the objects in S3, apply the usual [cross-account access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/). Or have you done this, and the Lambda function is still being denied access?

Comment: yep - have done that.  The lambda can quite happily read and write stuff to the s3 bucket and it works perfectly.  What it can't do is read stuff written from the cli - and that's what I need - to bulk load things from the cli and then read it through the lambda.

Comment: I think you're saying that if the S3 bucket owner uploads to the bucket then the 3rd account can access them. But if they're uploaded by the 2nd account (even granting bucket-owner-full-control), the 3rd account cannot access them. Presumably the bucket has `Bucket owner preferred` disabled? If enabled, that would help. But for right now, I presume the objects are owned by account 2. I believe that, given that account 1 has full control, it can take ownership - to do that, copy the objects over themselves, one by one, as the bucket owner. Test on one throwaway object first.

Comment: I got it working - had to find the "canonical id" of the 3rd account (which is a big 65 character string) and then do a --grant-read id={theid}

Comment: That would also work but the objects are still owned by account #2 (the uploader), which may or may not be what you want. It also makes accessing the objects from a new account #4 more difficult than if account #1 (the bucket owner) simply takes ownership of the objects.